# Swift first cell in tableView lost because add UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

the first cell in table view lost after push navigation from other page. why tableview not scroll to top position.

code
https://github.com/frankenly/ios-tableview-search-lost

https://github.com/frankenly/ios-tableview-search-lost/blob/main/StackOverflow/StackOverflow/ViewController.swift

[image: img]

Comment: You have to update top constraint of your tableview

Comment: sorry, I'm not understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly you can do one thing**

- Add search bar above tableview cell as shown in picture[image: searchBAr above cell in tableView]

**You can add below method**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Hope it's work for you.Thank you.